# org mode export fails to add newline between heading 4 and broad text

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Exporting to Latex PDF does not add a newline at the end of headings level 4.

Source:

```
* My one
** My one one
Plain text
*** my one one one
Plain text
**** my one one one one
Plain text
** My one two
```

Latex pdf output, see the inner heading, level 4:

[image]

I've read about `org-blank-before-new-entry`, but it looks like I'm looking for something *after* new entry of level 4.

Observing the generated LaTeX source, it turns out that level 4 is implemented by a `\begin{enumerate} \item`, that explains it.

How can I make org-mode add a newline after a header of level 4 or more?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to increase the maximum heading level when exporting.

See the [`H:` directive](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) for export settings.

In your case, level 4 is treated as a list item. Increasing `H:` will give you deeper heading levels.

Comment: I don't think that works for LaTeX, which appears to be limited to three levels

Comment: Not really, but you have to adjust other things as well, e.g. you might have to modify the org-latex-classes settings and/or the latex class that you are using (book, report and article behave differently).

Comment: In case it isn't clear, my previous comment was a reply to the comment by @rpluim.

Comment: I should have said "just setting H: on its own doesn't work for LaTeX". I'd be interested if you could add those "other things" to the answer.